# Validations for boolean type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Should I write any validations for attributes that have type *boolean* in my schema?

```
create_table "table_name", :force => true do |t|
  t.boolean "column", :default => true
end
```

Setting column to "asdasd" evaluates to false after .save. Need I be concerned about any weird values sent through POST (I'm writing the update method for my controller) could result in anything dangerous?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a good idea to validate, as otherwise you might get unexpected results. This should do you:

```
validates_inclusion_of :column, :in => [true, false]
```

That will also prevent null values. If you want to allow those, set `:allow_nil => true`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is better to validate, especially if that field is a sensitive one.If the field is like a field that enables some recurrent billing check and if some random string is sent, since your default is true,it will become true. It is a good thing to add validations, considering its so easier in Rails :)